# Saving an XLS Worksheet in Classic ASP, on a Windows2012 server running IIS8.5 - partly works

Tags: excel, com, asp-classic, save, dcom

So, a programmer of ours as left the nest and we moved to a Win2012 solution. The website runs fine, everything is good except for excel and in particular just one line of code fails.

We're running ASP classic for the website in IIS, Excel object gets created fine, the chart saves in the correct folder, but when it hits:

wb.SaveAs "D:\WEBSITES\test.xls"

the page conks out with a 500 error then leaves excel in memory in the task manager.
If I remove the save on the XLS, the JPG saves from the chart fine and the code continues and closes down excel properly. Since the code hasnt changed between a 2003 server and this 2012 server Im a bit perplexed as why it decides to fail now.

Any help with this would be most appreciated, I dont know do web stuff and when I do, its normally to sort out COM issues and since it runs, its just a major p.i.t.a. that this bit does not work. Thanks in advance ! :)

```
<%


    Dim xlapp   ' Our Excel App
    Dim wb      ' Our Workbook within the Excel App
    Dim ws      ' Our Worksheet within the Workbook 
    Dim crt     ' The chart object
    Dim SourceRange ' The Source Range for the chart object

    Const xlWorkSheet = -4167 
    Const xlLineMarkers = 65

    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Set wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Add(xlWorksheet)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)


    xlapp.DisplayAlerts = false


    Set SourceRange = ws.Range("A3:B6")
    Set crt = ws.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, 480, 383)
    crt.Chart.ChartWizard SourceRange, 3, , 2, 1, 0, 2, "Virgin Chaser Report " & formatdatetime(now(),2)
    crt.Chart.ChartType = 51


    crt.Chart.HasTitle = True
    crt.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Virgin Chaser Report " & formatdatetime(now(),2)
    crt.Chart.ChartTitle.AutoScaleFont = false
    crt.Chart.ChartTitle.font.Name = "Arial"
    crt.Chart.ChartTitle.font.Size = 12
    crt.Chart.ChartTitle.font.Strikethrough = False
    crt.Chart.ChartTitle.font.Superscript = False
    crt.Chart.ChartTitle.font.Subscript = False
    crt.Chart.ChartTitle.font.OutlineFont = False
    crt.Chart.ChartTitle.font.Shadow = False    

    crt.Chart.Export "D:\WEBSITES\test.jpg"
    wb.SaveAs "D:\WEBSITES\test.xls"


    wb.Saved = True
    Set crt = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    xlapp.Quit
    Set xlapp = Nothing


response.end()

%>
```

Comment: You're not supposed to use Excel in a server context...but, people do anyways. Can you take that code, put it in a VBS file and run it interactively on the server and succeed? Does the process have access to the output directory? You should try to capture the error being returned by SaveAs. You haven't shown us what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Found it: (someone else's fix on stack overflow - this works with Office 2000 too) on Win2012, IIS 8.5

Finally got it fixed. Here was what worked, in case anyone in the future has this same error.

We added BOTH folders:

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop